What is the hashTypeCode?
After a transaction is serialised ready for signature or signature verification, a 4 byte hashTypeCode must be added (step 9 here). As it's derived from a single byte, it has 256 possible values.
What is the Hash Type Code?

Also known as SigHash, it is an instruction (in a transaction input) from a signer to a verifier to say "to get this to verify, you'll need to construct a transaction template like this." For each input in a transaction, a different hashtypeCode might be used.
It is defined in interpreter.h of the Bitcoin Core software:
/** Signature hash types/flags */
enum
{
    SIGHASH_ALL = 1,
    SIGHASH_NONE = 2,
    SIGHASH_SINGLE = 3,
    SIGHASH_ANYONECANPAY = 0x80,
};

From Raghav Sood:

SIGHASH_ANYONECANPAY is combined with the previous three via a bitwise
& (effectively addition in this case), for a total of six possible
values.




hashTypeCode
hashTypeCode Identifier
Tx fields used in signature




0x01
SIGHASH_ALL
All inputs and outputs.


0x02
SIGHASH_NONE 
All inputs. No outputs.


0x03
SIGHASH_SINGLE 
All input. One output.


0x81
SIGHASH_ANYONECANPAY & SIGHASH_ALL
One input. All outputs.


0x82
SIGHASH_ANYONECANPAY & SIGHASH_NONE
One input. No outputs.


0x83
SIGHASH_ANYONECANPAY & SIGHASH_SINGLE
One input and its corresponding output.



The procedure is described at bitcoin.it
See also:
bitcoin.org

The sighash type is decided by the signer when spending an input, not the creator of an output, as it's part of the signature they produce.

@PieterWuille Thanks, I have some confusion around this atm... will update more as I figure it out
